# D3D11 CreateVertexShader issue when using custom shader class

Tags: c++, graphics, direct3d

I'm trying to abstract some shader related code away into a small shader class which I'll hopefully modify further to allow for glsl in addition to hlsl. The issue however is when I try to create the shader using the data from the shader class.

The load and compile code from the shader class:

```
bool Shader::LoadAndCompile() {
    mIsLoadedAndCompiled = false;

    // Setup the file name, extension and path
    std::string filePath = XOF_FILEPATHS::RESOURCES_SHADERS;
    filePath.append( mFileName + 
        ( ( mType == XOF_SHADER_TYPE::VERTEX )? "VS" : "PS" ) + ".hlsl" );

    // Convert to unicode for file path
    std::wstring filePathW = std::wstring( filePath.begin(), filePath.end() );

    // Try and compile the shader
    std::string version = ( mType == XOF_SHADER_TYPE::VERTEX )? "vs_5_0" : "ps_5_0";
    ID3DBlob *codeBlob = nullptr, *errorBlob = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = D3DCompileFromFile( filePathW.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr, 
        "main", version.c_str(), 0, 0, &codeBlob, &errorBlob );

    if( FAILED( hr ) ) {
        _com_error err( hr );
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Shader failed to compile: " << 
            mFileName << ": " << err.ErrorMessage() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Copy compiled shader data to data member pointer
    mDataSize = codeBlob->GetBufferSize();
    mData = new U8[mDataSize];
    std::memcpy( mData, codeBlob->GetBufferPointer(), mDataSize );

    mIsLoadedAndCompiled = true;
    return mIsLoadedAndCompiled;
```

}

This is an effort to replace this code:

```
    hr = D3DCompileFromFile( L"./Resources/Shaders/PassThroughVS.hlsl", nullptr, nullptr,
    "main", "vs_5_0", 0, 0, &mTempVertexShaderBlob, &errorBlob );
```

However, when I try to create the shader using the buffer from the shader class via this code:

```
    hr = mD3DDevice->CreateVertexShader( mTempTestMaterial->GetShader( XOF_SHADER_TYPE::VERTEX, 0 )->GetData(),
    mTempTestMaterial->GetShader( XOF_SHADER_TYPE::VERTEX, 0 )->GetDataSize(), nullptr, &mTempVertexShader );
```

I get the error: Encoded Vertex Shader size doesn't match specified size.

I've confirmed that by replacing the first parameter in CreateVertexShader with the "blob" used in the original D3DCompileFromFile class it works (even using the size information from the shader class) but for some reason it absolutely refuses to work using the data buffer from the shader class.

I saw a thread suggest changing the data buffer to BYTE but this didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: If you've verified that using the blob directly works correctly, then obviously the value returned by your own class's `GetData` and `GetDataSize` aren't returning the same values.  Assuming these are just getters for `mData` and `mDataSize`, your setup code looks correct, so this should just be a matter of finding out where the corruption occurs.  Try using a memory write-watch.

Comment: Thanks for your input, have fixed the issue. Taking some time away and re-writing the code in question did the trick this time.